# What is an effective way to organize tasks for a new project?

Tags: project-management, specifications, task-organization

Is there a practical solution to organizing the initial tasks for a new project?

To elaborate, imagine the features/stories/goals are laid out for a project. How might one go about organizing those into sane tasks for the first few versions?

The scenario I typically have in mind has the features listed as a high-level reference for what the end user-experience should involve. The tasks for constructing such features are then broken down into chunks (such as "create interface for X component"). Such a task is not necessarily "tied" to only that feature and may be useful when building subsequent features. Is breaking features down into small, code-able solutions valid? Or should they be slightly removed from any specific implementation?

I do not expect that there is one "right" answer to this question, but I am looking for a fairly pragmatic and unobtrusive approach.

As a note, I'm looking for solutions that are independent of any tools or "systems" used for managing the tasks themselves.

Comment: You'd probably get a lot of mileage out of studying Agile methods, especially [user stories.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story)

Comment: @Robery Harvey, thanks for the suggestion. I've looked into them in the past, but from what I understand, they're meant to be very sparse regarding actual implementation details. Do the fine-grained issues-at-hand still get tracked alongside those stories? Or is the gritty detail managed by the developer(s) working on the story as they implement the feature?

Comment: That's all part of the Agile process.

Answer (score 1):

There definitely isn't a "one size fits all" solution to this.

For most of my projects however, I usually start out brainstorming in TextEdit what I want my program to do. By writing it out, I can easily self-reflect, and decide what to scrap or what to improve. Drawing a possible GUI out on paper can help to, depending on the nature of the project.

After a semi-definite plan is made, I'll usually make a few test modules to see if what I want is practical (or possible).

Last, I basically piece together the test programs I made into one application, and repeat the process indefinitely.